# Is there any option to select records between 10 kilo meter with Firestore Geopoint node js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I don't want to use Geo fire-store any custom code in Node JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not currently have built-in support for geoqueries, such as retrieving items within a certain range.

Add-on libraries like GeoFirestore are the only option, unless you want to build something yourself (in which case you're essentially rebuilding the library).

Comment: Is there any way I can override Geo fire-store library in node JavaScript app.

Comment: There may be libraries for use in Node (I haven't checked), but otherwise it's typically not very hard to extract the code. See my video on the subject from back before anyone created a GeoFirestore library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q